# .findControl() null pointer exception and crashing ASPX server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have the following code:

```
private Ext.Net.Store getStore(string name)
{
    return (Ext.Net.Store)DUOSPage.FindControl(name);
}
```

and

```
getStore("store").DataSource = someList;
```

I can verify that both the "store" object and "someList" are actually present in the page. It seems to me that FindControl cannot be found. However, am am getting a

```
someList = Count = Cannot evaluate expression because a thread is stopped at a point where garbage collection is impossible, possibly because the code is optimized.
```

aswell as the local server crashes. To me that means that the element might be in the page and found but it somehow causes the server to cringe and crash.

Any ideas on what is wrong here? Why would this crash the ASPX server?

EDIT:

The error prompt gives me this:

```
Description:
Stopped working

Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
Problem Signature 01:   webdev.webserver20.exe
Problem Signature 02:   10.0.0.0
Problem Signature 03:   4ba204ca
Problem Signature 04:   ****
Problem Signature 05:   1.0.0.0
Problem Signature 06:   4fe36c1c
Problem Signature 07:   3ce
Problem Signature 08:   c
Problem Signature 09:   System.NullReferenceException
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
Locale ID:  ****
```

Comment: The server crashing is *very odd*... however, if FindControl returns `null` then there is no Control named `name` *currently* in the *naming container* for DUOSPage. (Has it been *removed* from the Control Tree for some strange reason? Is it a "server-side" control?)

Comment: What messages are logged when the "ASPX server" crashes? Does the AppPool worker restart? Hang? (A YSOD/error message screen isn't a crash, mind.)

Comment: I added the error output to the post

Comment: Try removing DUOSPage. It may be that you're at a point in the page lifecycle where the control is recognized as a child of the Page, but not yet categorized as a child of DUOSPage. I've experienced something like this myself recently.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove DUOSPage?" How would I go about finding the element without using the page reference?

Comment: You doesn't make some redirect near this `getStore("store").DataSource = someList;
` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be confusing two different things. You mention that you can verify that "store" is present in the *page*, which I assume means you see it in your HTML markup, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's available to the server. Make sure you set runat="server" to ensure a server-side control is generated for your "store" element.

Comment: It is in fact marked as "runat" and when I dig through the class itself in debug it is infact present and listed

Comment: What class are you digging through in debug? You mean when you look at the DUOSPage class you see the Store control in it?

Comment: Yes, its a Page class type. If you dig around you can find a list of all the elements on the page.

Comment: The elements on the page are different from the controls in the Page class. When you're debugging, take a look at the DUOSPage.Controls property, and see if the Store control is in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the solution, I found it here:

http://winmike.blogspot.com/2011/02/aspnet-findcontrol-returns-null-for.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ext.NET, or even if you're not, Ext.NET includes the Ext.NET.Utilities library (not dependent on Ext.NET).

The **Utilities** library includes the `ControlUtils` class with a whole pile of "*FindControl*" helpers to work-around limitations of the native Page.FindControl Method.

There may be an option in `ControlUtils` to avoid this issue, although I'd need to see a more complete sample to say 100% what the best solution/call would be. Something like the following might work.

**Example**

```
return Ext.Net.Utilities.ControlUtils.FindControl<Store>(this, name);
```

The `ControlUtils.FindControlByClientID(string)` Method might be helpful as well.

https://github.com/extnet/Ext.NET.Utilities (MIT licensed)

Anyways, the native ASP.NET Page.FindControl() is limiting, although there are other options with greater flexibility, and you already have those options available on your Page.

Hope this helps.